# Is python sys.stderr.write atomic? How to determine thread safety of builtin functions?

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety, disassembly, atomic

I'm trying to understand atomicity of this command with

```
import dis
import sys
dis.dis(sys.stderr.write)
```

However, I get "TypeError: don't know how to disassemble builtin_function_or_method objects"

How to determine atomicity of python built-in functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't disassemble `sys.stderr.write` - it's not a python function, but a function written in C and only available in binary after installation.

Being a C function, [it is implicitly thread-safe because of the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL)](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/466354-standard-output-thread-safe).